# Tying several objects to same ActionListener

Tags: java, events, actionlistener

I'm trying to get several instances of an object (Blorb) to react to the same SwingTimer in the class that creates the objects (BlorbWorld). I'm trying to pass the ActionListener related to the SwingTimer in BlorbWorld to each Blorb it makes. ActionPerformed works in BlorbWorld in accordance to the SwingTimer but actionPerformed in Blorb does nothing.

I'm doing all this because I want to make all the Blorbs react to the same timer so they move, and I don't want to use an Array.

Comment: Verbal descriptions of what you're trying to do can be vague and open to interpretation, and hard to answer in specific terms. Whenever possible, post the code that you've tried and be specific about what's not working about it.

Comment: `and I don't want to use an Array.` - Use an ArrayList instead. This is normally the way groups of objects are animated at the same time.

Comment: 1. add code of what you are trying
2. from what I get from your question you could have `Blorb` implement `ActionListener` and add every `Blorb` to the `Timer`.